# Como puedo realizar una consulta where que incluya un case when?

Tags: sql-server

El tema es el siguiente: tengo una tabla **tblQuotation** en el cual existen los campos **IN_IdCustomer,IN_PricingID y IN_IdEComercial** para los cuales lo que desearía realizar es una consulta dependiendo del tipo de usuario ya sea **customer,pricing o ejecutivo comercial.**

eso puedo saberlo por que hay una tabla que me lo indica **tblUser**.

```
select *from tblQuotation 
where (Case 
when (select groupID from tblUser where userID=@userID)=5 then IN_IdCustomer=@userID 
when (select groupID from tblUser where userID=@userID)=15 then IN_PricingID=@userID 
when (select groupID from tblUser where userID=@userID)=24 then IN_IdEComercial=@userID end)
```

En mi codigo se puede ver que si el id de grupo es 5,15 o 24 corresponde al tipo de usuario Customer,Pricing y E.Comercial respectivamente, entonces lo que quisiera saber es como puedo hacer que mi consulta dependiendo del tipo de usuario me pueda filtrar el campo que corresponda(**IN_IdCustomer,IN_PricingID y IN_IdEComercial**).

Por ejemplo si un usuario que le pase por el **parametro @userID** sea de **Pricing**, osea que el **groupID** sea 15 ,el **where** lo filtre por el campo **IN_PricingID**.

Comment: para que base de datos?

Comment: Es para Microsoft SQL

Comment: o sea.. sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A manera de guía te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
select * from tblQuotation 
where (Case 
when (select groupID from tblUser where userID=@userID)=5 then IN_IdCustomer 
when (select groupID from tblUser where userID=@userID)=15 then IN_PricingID 
when (select groupID from tblUser where userID=@userID)=24 then IN_IdEComercial end)=@userID
```

Faltaria incluir el `else`; ya que no mencionas error en tu sentencia (es decir es un SQL válido) solo se quita la comparación que haces dentro del `CASE` para con este determinar el valor a devolver y compararlo con el `@userID`.